# Prime Number Theorem estimate

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

## Update

I have updated this question in light of the illuminating answers given below, which clearly point out my mistake. However, I still maintain that Legendre's original guess had some validity - it would seem, as the asymptotic starting point for the plot $\log x - \frac{x}{\pi(x)}$ as given below:

[image]

It clearly will begin to converge to $1$ eventually *(_Mathematica_ has a limit of not much more than PrimePi[$1 \times 10^{14}$])*, but it does appear to have a starting point of around Legendre's first guess, so my initial question still holds in this regard.

As an additional question, does anyone know how far along the numberline one would have to go for $\log x - \frac{x}{\pi(x)}$ to reach close to (let's say $\pm 0.01$) $1$? Is there an asymptotic statement for this?

## Original question

Could it be that the bounds for [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_formula), given as $\frac{e}{\sqrt{2\pi}} = 1.0844375514...$ provide a more accurate 'guess' than [Legendre's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_constant) of $1.08366$ as an estimate for the convergence of the prime counting function as illustrated [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeNumberTheorem.html)?

The discrepancy is illustrated below in a plot of $\log x - \frac{x}{\pi(x)}$:

[image]

Compare:

[image][image]

If this were the case, would it not give a closed form to the approximation?

## Edit

A plot of $\frac{x}{\pi(x)}$, $\log x+1.084437\dots$ and $\log x+1$ in response to Eric Naslund's answers below.

[image]

Comment: Afterthought: If this were the case, would it have implications for the RH?

Comment: It has been long proven that Legendre's constant cannot be other than $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your value is a worse approximation. The true approximation/value of Legendre's constant is $1$.

By the prime number theorem, $$\pi(x)=\frac{x}{\log x}+\frac{x}{\log^{2}x}+O\left(\frac{x}{\log^{3}x}\right)=\frac{x}{\log x}\left(1+\frac{1}{\log x}+O\left(\frac{1}{\log^{2}x}\right)\right)$$ and so $$\frac{x}{\pi(x)}=\log x\left(1+\frac{1}{\log x}+O\left(\frac{1}{\log^{2}x}\right)\right)^{-1} $$

$$=\log x-1+O\left(\frac{1}{\log x}\right).$$ Your choice of $B$  approximates $\frac{x}{\pi(x)}$  by $\log x-1.084437\dots,$ and since $1.08366$  is closer to $1$, the true value, than $1.084437$, your constant will be a worse asymptotically.

Comment: @ Eric Naslund, please see edit above. If the true value of Legendre's constant (which has only historical value only, if I understand correctly) is $1$, then why does $\pi(x)$ appear to converge to $\log x+1.08366$ (or $\log x+1.084437…$)? By your rational, why is (the usual value of) Legendre's constant given as $1.08366$, and not $1.08$, or $1.00001$, etc? Perhaps I am missing the point?

Comment: Is it of no consequence that numerical evidence supports the usual value of the constant $1.08366$?

Comment: @martin: I had a sign error, it should be $\log x-1$, and it should be $\log x -1.08366$ and $\log x-1.084437$ in your plots. To answer you question: The function will converge better to $\log x-1$ if you go far.

Comment: Note: Where I spoke about convergence in the above comment, please read, "...then why does $\log x - \frac{n}{\pi (n)}$ appear to converge to $1.08366$, (or $\frac {e}{\sqrt 2\pi}$) ..."

Comment: @ Eric Naslund, whoops! Should have noticed that!

Comment: So, are you saying that the top plot, a plot of $\log x - \frac{x}{\pi(x)}$ would converge to $1$ if you went far enough? If not, how do you explain this phenomenon?

Comment: @Martin: I am not sure I understand the confusion. On the plot you added to the question, $\log x-1$ is a better approximation. In the limit, $\log x-\frac{x}{\pi(x)}$ converges to $1$.

Comment: @ Eric Naslund, I have updated the question based on your response. In hindsight, the question should have been phrased: Why does the asymptotic upper 'bound' (if there can be such a thing) for the first plot appear to be closer to Legendre's first guess, and would this have anything to do with the bounds for Stirling's approximation?